# Is it possible to pass an object to usercontrol in front-end?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls

Is there anyway to pass an object to an usercontrol through the frontend tags? I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

**Backend**

```
   public Range Range { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Popular channel range
        Range Range = new Range() 
        { 
            Min = 0, 
            Max = 8 
        };
    }
```

**Frontend**

```
<uc:PopularItems Range="<%=Range %>" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use `<%=` with a server control. You should use `<%#` and databind:

**Backend**

```
   [Bindable(true)]
   public Range Range { get; set; }
```

**Frontend**

```
<uc:PopularItems ID="myControl" Range="<%# Range %>" runat="server" />
```

**Backend of the page**

```
   if(! IsPostBack) {
      myControl.DataBind();

      // or, to bind each control in the page:
      // this.DataBind();
   }
```